# Wiring a Mosfet for Pulses

Tags: mosfet, schematics, pulse, diagram

BACKGROUND:

For sometime now I've been in need of a pulsed power supply that can put out 200 V pulses with a minimum pulse width of 400 nS. After researching effective switching devices, I decided upon using a Mosfet.

Unfortunately, my research has not yielded any schematics or techniques for how I can wire a Mosfet to provide a select number of pulses per second at a pulse width that I can determine (not like a controller, but just something that I can figure out).

QUESTION:

I was curious if anyone knew how I should wire a mosfet to get a select number of pulses per second and a minimum pulse width.

EDIT: I don't need the supply to be adjustable, I only need to be able to know what the number of pulses per second will be (through equations and the likes) and how long each pulse will last (pulse width).

Comment: You'll need a 200 volt supply too and you'll also need to specify what your load is and how much rise/fall time extremes you can live with.

Comment: You need to elaborate on "a pulse width that I can control". What are the minimum and maximum pulse widths you need? What resolution do you need in selecting the pulse width? How accurate must the timing be? How will you change the pulse width? Are the pulses continuous or a specific number of pulses?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It should have been a pulse width that I can determine, not like an active controller or anything to that effect. I'll modify the question to encompass that.

Comment: Use a microcontroller and gate drivers

Comment: @Andyaka The load is a thyratron, unfortunately I don't know much about it beyond that the impedance is 50-100 ohms. The minimum rise time between 25% and 75% of the amplitude needs to be 1.5 kV/uS, which should be easily achievable by any modern mosfet.

Comment: @DKNguyen How should I go about wiring the microcontrollers? Also, I don't need it to be adjustable. I only want to be able to know (via equations or the likes ) what the pulse width will be and how many pulses are produced per second.

Comment: @JamesLi You basically just apply power and decoupling capacitors and a reset pull resistor. Maybe an oscillator if you want an external one. 400ns minimum is one thing, but resolution is another which you never specified. Look at a PICAXE or Nucleo-32 or Arduino.

Comment: Or buy a signal generator for $50 to produce the control pulses

Comment: @DKNguyen Would these units be able to handle an output voltage of 200 V? If so, how should I go about wiring them?

Comment: You need to do some research to fill in awareness gaps before anyone can help you further. Look into gate drivers mentioned. Is it an issue that your hands can't handle the forces on a crane's arm when you pull the control levers?